# Can the pre and post intervention periods be reversed in order in CausalImpact in R?

Tags: r, causalimpact, bsts

In CausalImpact library in R, usually the pre period is considered as the period where the campaign was inactive and the post period is considered as the period after the intervention of the campaign. So the data for pre-period is considered as 0 and data for post period is considered as 1. Can we interchange this? Can we consider the pre period to be the period where the campaign is effective i.e, 1 and post period to be the period where the campaign is inactive i.e., 0?

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation.